# What are the colony worlds of the Queendom of Sol?

Tags: queendom-of-sol

I can remember that the colony at Barnard's Star is eventually dubbed "Sorrow" by Conrad Mursk and there's a colony around one of the Wolf series stars called Pup. But, I seem to remember that there are half a dozen colony stars listed in *Lost in Transmission*.

What are they and more importantly what are their worlds called?

Comment: [A few are mentioned here potentially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZU93.png). Appears to be four...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Unfortunately that's the one I know I know the name of; Sorrow, or P2, around Barnard's Star. The other worlds are the gas giants of Barnard's Star.